# Rails : ActionController::UnknownFormat when adding image in ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

hi i am trying to upload a form via **ajax** , the form works fine when i send without a attachment  but when i attach  it gives **ActionController::UnknownFormat**  , I am using activestorage migration for this

````
@items_list= Item.where(:category_id => params[:item][:category_id])
  respond_to do |f|
    f.js
  end```
````

Comment: Can you share what the params look like in the log or console when getting sent?

Comment: <ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"test", "description"=>"test", "price"=>"test", "category_id"=>"1", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f3371021fb0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20220207-54727-1qybe2z.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2022-01-31 15-38-48.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2022-01-31 15-38-48.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">} permitted: true>

Comment: Please add that to the question, also, doesn;t it say what format it is being sent as?

Comment: the irony is , if i use method like render plain: 'test , it works fine but not when respond_to :js

Comment: fixed:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119513/rails-not-making-ajax-request-when-file-field-is-present-in-form

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.